# Excel Date separate with =DAY(), =MONTH() and =YEAR()

Tags: excel

it is a very easy question but I have problem with the functions =DAY(), =MONTH() and =YEAR(). It wont work and gives me error. I dont want csv.

Excel Sheet:

```
A1 19.03.2023
A2 =DAY(A1)
```

but A2 gives #VALUE error. The Format is in General for A1 and A2 even if I set to Date nothing changes.

Comment: Cell `A1` is date or date stored as text?

Comment: What is result of `=ISTEXT(A1)`?

Comment: you should put in cell A1 valid date . to do so  use one of that format 19/03/2023  Or 2023-03-19  Or 45004  that represent the real value of that date in windows (come from inserting to A1 19/03/2023  and format it as number  )

Comment: @Harun24hr its setted as "General" if you mean that.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld =True

Comment: @CihanDincel Then try `=TEXTBEFORE(A1,".")` to get date from that string.

Answer (score 0):

One option, if it must be done inside Excel, could be to use SPLIT and CONCAT to bring it to the format you want. The CONCAT could even be re-ordered if needed.

TEXTSPLIT(A1,".")

CONCAT(B2,"/",C2,"/",D2)

[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UpXM.png)

Another option (and the option I use 99/100, would be to pull the data into Power Query, transform as needed, and drop it back into another sheet (or even another workbook) cleaned up and ready to use.

Assuming that you actually have a header "Date" in A1, and the data in question was in A2:

1. Ctrl+T to turn it into a Table
2. From the Data tab, "Get Data from Table/Range"
3. From within Power Query, right-click the Date column, select "Replace values".
4. Value to Find "."
5. Replace with (leave blank)
6. Results: 19032023

[Power Query 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpH5H.png)

Alternatively, you could use "Split Column" by delimiter to get "19", "03", and "2023" in separate columns, then move them into any order you desire, and then merge the columns with a "/" delimiter.
[Power Query 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5VT1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MID function to extract DAY, MONTH and YEAR:

```
=MID(A1,1,2)
```

The concatenate the individual values:

```
=MID(A1,1,2) & "/" & MID(A1,4,2) & "/" & MID(A1,7,4)
```

Finally, wrap them up with the VALUE function:

```
=VALUE(MID(A1,1,2) & "/" & MID(A1,4,2) & "/" & MID(A1,7,4))
```

Result should be something like this: `45004`

Change data type to Short Date: `19/03/2023`